# Testing CompletableFuture.allOf. join takes forever

Tags: java, junit, mockito, completable-future

I am trying to test a method that uses CompletableFuture.allOf.
I mock the futures so that they return the needed value when joined.
for some reason which I can't understand. join() of result takes forever.
any help will do!

Thanks in advance.

```
    @Mock private CompletableFuture<String> future1; // for sequence test
    @Mock private CompletableFuture<String> future2; // for sequence test
    @Mock private CompletableFuture<String> future3; // for sequence test

    private BBService bbServiceTest;

    @Test
    public void testSequence() {
        final String[] expectedResults = {"res1", "res2", "res3"};
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new Vector<>();

        when(future1.join()).thenReturn(expectedResults[0]);
        when(future2.join()).thenReturn(expectedResults[1]);
        when(future3.join()).thenReturn(expectedResults[2]);

        futures.add(future1);
        futures.add(future2);
        futures.add(future3);

        bbServiceTest.sequence(futures).join();
        Assert.assertTrue(future1.isDone());
        Assert.assertTrue(future2.isDone());
        Assert.assertTrue(future3.isDone());

//        for (int i = 0; i < actualResults.size(); i++) {
//            Assert.assertEquals(expectedResults[i], actualResults.get(i));
//        }
    }
```

sequence method inside BBService:

```
    public <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> sequence(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futuresList) {
        return CompletableFuture
                .allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])) // (1)
                .thenApply(v ->
                        futuresList.stream()
                                .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Thats because your `futures` never get completed. `CompletableFuture.allOf` returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given `CompletableFutures` complete.

`future1.complete()`, `future2.complete()` and `future3.complete()` never get called.

`CompletableFuture.join()` returns the result if the future is completed. Because you mock the futures in your code they return the strings defined in `expectedResults` on a `join` even if they're not completed. But that's exactly the problem. They don't complete. That's why the test doesn't finish.

I adjusted your Test class a little to demonstrate how it works:

```java
public class FutureTest {
    @Test
    public void testSequence1() {
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = getFutures();
        CompletableFuture<Void> myCombinedFuture = sequence(futures);
        // here we complete each future
        futures.forEach(future -> future.complete("future-completed"));
        myCombinedFuture.join();

        // this works because we completed all futures before
        Assert.assertTrue(myCombinedFuture.isDone());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSequence2() {
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = getFutures();
        CompletableFuture<Void> myCombinedFuture = sequence(futures);
        futures.get(0).complete("completed-future1");
        futures.get(1).complete("completed-future2");

        myCombinedFuture.join();
        // this does not work because future3 is not completed -> we wait forever
        Assert.assertTrue(myCombinedFuture.isDone());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSequence3() {
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = getFutures();
        CompletableFuture<Void> myCombinedFuture = sequence(futures);
        futures.get(0).complete("completed-future1");
        futures.get(1).complete("completed-future2");

        // complete future 3 asynchronous after 2 seconds
        futures.get(2).completeAsync(() -> {
            // wait for 2 seconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "completed-future3";
        });

        myCombinedFuture.join();
        // after 2 seconds all futures are completed and the test will pass
        Assert.assertTrue(myCombinedFuture.isDone());
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> sequence(
            List<CompletableFuture<String>> futuresList) {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(
            futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    }

    public List<CompletableFuture<String>> getFutures() {
        return List.of(
                new CompletableFuture<>(),
                new CompletableFuture<>(),
                new CompletableFuture<>()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you!
Can you help with an idea of how to test this method?

Comment: @AvishaiYaniv I edited the answer with some examples. hope it helps.

Comment: It boils down to [Don't mock a type you don't own!](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-a-type-you-dont-own) from Mockito's wiki 